# Connector patch between subplots with animation not visible (matplotlib)

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am using an artist animation method with 5 subplots. There is one static plot on the left, with 3 smaller animated imshow plots to the right (the colorbar is the 5th). I have successfully used ConnectionPatch to connect subplots to show where the data is coming from, but only on static plots. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the patches to show up on the animation. I've tried to include the patch in the image artist list, tried to update the figure with the artist instead of the axis (which I guess doesn't make much sense), among other things. It will be very difficult to extract a working example due to the complexity of the plot, but maybe someone has a tip.

Could setting the facecolor to 'white' with the animation savefig_kwargs be covering up the connector lines? If so, how do I change the z order of the patch/facecolor?

Comment: 1. Don't be lazy. Make a MVE. 2. Random guess: are your patches within the x- and y-limits of your plot? Matplotlib doesn't automatically update the data extent with manually added patches.

Comment: Dissertation defense tomorrow made me have to prioritize and this was a Hail Mary before I just added lines manually in Powepoint. I will circle back around and try to either make it work with the posted answer below or post a MVE. Chastisement noted.

Comment: Good luck, and have fun during the defense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a minimal working example, I can only tell you that it **is** possible to use a `ConnectionPatch` in an animation. However, as seen below, one has to recreate it for every frame.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import matplotlib.animation
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = np.array([6,3.6])*0.7

x = np.linspace(-3,3)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
f = lambda x,y: (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)+1.5
Z = f(X,Y)

bins=np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 16)
cols = plt.cm.PuOr((bins[:-1]-Z.min())/(Z.max()-Z.min()))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios=[34,53], width_ratios=[102,53])
fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[:,0])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])

ax.imshow(Z, cmap="PuOr")
rec = plt.Rectangle([-.5,-.5], width=9, height=9, edgecolor="crimson", fill=False, lw=2)
conp = ConnectionPatch(xyA=[-0.5,0.5], xyB=[9.5,4], coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
                      axesA=ax3, axesB=ax, arrowstyle="-|>", zorder=25, shrinkA=0, shrinkB=1,
                      mutation_scale=20, fc="w", ec="crimson", lw=2)
ax3.add_artist(conp)
ax.add_artist(rec)
im = ax3.imshow(Z[:9,:9], cmap="PuOr", vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max())
ticks = np.array([0,4,8])
ax3.set_yticks(ticks); ax3.set_xticks(ticks)
ax2.hist(Z[:9,:9].flatten(), bins=bins)

def ins(px,py):
    global rec, conp, histpatches
    ll = [px-.5,py-.5]
    rec.set_xy(ll)
    conp.remove()
    conp = ConnectionPatch(xyA=[-0.5,0.5], xyB=[px+9.5,py+4], coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
                      axesA=ax3, axesB=ax, arrowstyle="-|>", zorder=25, shrinkA=0, shrinkB=1,
                      mutation_scale=20, fc="w", ec="crimson", lw=2)
    ax3.add_patch(conp)
    data = Z[px:px+9,py:py+9]
    im.set_data(data)
    ax3.set_xticklabels(ticks+px)
    ax3.set_yticklabels(ticks+py)
    ax2.clear()
    ax2.set_ylim(0,60)
    h, b_, patches = ax2.hist(data.flatten(), bins=bins, ec="k", fc="#f1a142")
    [pat.set_color(cols[i]) for i, pat in enumerate(patches)]

def func(p):
    px,py = p
    ins(px, py)

phi = np.linspace(0.,2*np.pi)
r = np.sin(2*phi)*20+np.pi/2
xr = (r*np.cos(phi)).astype(np.int8)
yr = (r*np.sin(phi)).astype(np.int8)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.93,bottom=0.11,left=0.04,right=0.96,hspace=0.26,wspace=0.15)
frames = np.c_[xr+20, yr+20]
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=frames, interval=300, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This looks very promising; thank you. Will pick my way through it asap. I will have to re-write to use FuncAnimation instead of ArtistAnimation though.

Comment: You could have prevented that by supplying a [mcve] in the first place.

Comment: Certainly True. Thanks for your help.